# How to save cursor in activity?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, cursor

I'm population my listView using Cursor, but when I navigate away from my activity and then return back my listview is empty. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(context);
db.open();
Cursor c = db.getAll();
db.close();

startManagingCursor(c);
String[] columns = new String[] { ... };
int[] to = new int[] { ... };
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, c, columns, to);
this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

...

}
```

I've seen here questions about saving position of Cursor, but not the Cursor itself. Probably I just missing something, shall I save my cursor (how can I do it?) or it's better(faster, cheaper) to create new cursor every time using my DBadapter?

Thanks

Comment: I see you already make use of `startManagingCursor` Does this happen if you comment out the `db.close()` method?

Comment: thanks, indeed if I comment out `db.close()` my list doesn't disapear, but aren't we suppose to close connection every time after we use DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startManagingCursor()` makes your `close()` call unnecessary. As long as you didnt get exceptions about not finalizing or closing your cursor you have done anything right.

Comment: Do I need to take any other actions to make sure the connection is closed and memory is freed? e.g. add something to `onPause()` or something similar? thanks

Comment: It is all mentioned in the documentation: This method allows the activity to take care of managing the given Cursor's lifecycle for you based on the activity's lifecycle. That is, when the activity is stopped it will automatically call `deactivate()` on the given Cursor, and when it is later restarted it will call `requery()` for you. When the activity is destroyed, all managed Cursors will be closed automatically.